# how to migrate oracle database data from my pc to virtualbox oracle database

Tags: oracle11g, virtualbox, database-migration

I have an Oracle Database 11g data on my local PC.

Now I want to import this data to Oracle VirtualBox machine where I also have Oracle Database 11g.

Can somebody suggest me the procedure how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I have my solution for my problem. In the virtual box, when I create a new connection in oracle database, I place my local IP address instead of localhost, username and password as it is in my local PC. And it works !